# Windsor container: how to replace ISpecialService implementation at resolving time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, castle-windsor

I have several Windsor Installers at my ASP.NET MVC application. They register controllers and services. Most of them depend on `ICurrentService`.

Controller example:

```
public DataStructureController(
            IMapper mapper,
            DataEntityService dataEntityService,
            FieldDefinitionService fieldDefinitionService,
            CompanyService companyService,
            ICurrentService currentService,
            SelectListService selectListService,
            EnumResourceService enumResourceService,
            WebPreprocessService preprocessService)
            : base(preprocessService)
{
   // Initialise variables code here
}
```

Service example:

```
public DataEntityService(DataEntitySpec specification, ICurrentService currentService)
            : base(specification)
{
    // Initialise variables code here
}
```

In my test classes I have a method, that I call once in `[TestInitialize]` marked method, or on/many times in `[TestMethod]` marked methods:

```
private static ICurrentService MockCurrentUser(User user)
{
    var currentUserSerivceMock = new Mock<ICurrentService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    currentUserSerivceMock.Setup(x => x.UserId).Returns(user.Id);
    currentUserSerivceMock.Setup(x => x.CompanyId).Returns(user.CompanyProfile.Id);

    return currentUserSerivceMock.Object;
}
```

I want to replace ICurrentService implementation when calling the `container.Resolve<>` method, because it depends on HttpContext, that isn't available when unit tests run. Is it possible and how do I do it with minimum code?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your problem.  Are you trying to test at the controller level?  Why can't you just pass the mocked ICustomerService object directly into the controller?  I'm not seeing any container Resolve calls (that's a good thing).  What's the actual issue?

Comment: @kellyb, I want more elegant solution than spaghetty code contains constructors of services (almost all of them depends on ICurrentService) and controllers (depends on many services). Any change in dependencies means verifying of all tests.

Comment: Create an implementation of ICurrentService that decides which implementation of ICurrentService it uses. It can store the implementation and pass all method calls through to this implementation. You can then test your implementation of ICurrentService seperately from the controllers by passing in the various states of HttpContext as necessary. The controllers can just assume that they will be talking with an appropriate ICurrentService implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a fake `HttpContext`:

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null),
new HttpResponse(null));
```

And then in your tests:

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
        new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null),
        new HttpResponse(null));
}
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    HttpContext.Current = null;
}
```

*Reference: http://caioproiete.net/en/fake-mock-httpcontext-without-any-special-mocking-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Register your implementation as a Fallback with Windsor. Then in your test register your mock instance.  That or just build up a dedicated instance of the container for your test and register what you like.